# System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently I developed the Xamarin.Forms Application by using Facebook login, after login, it will response to Second Page but the error display as below:

**System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBZsF.png)

Thank You.

Comment: hit "break" and then use the debugger to find the exact source of the exception.

Comment: Pretty straight forward, whatever key you're using to access an item in your collection (`List`, `Dictionary`, etc) doesn't exist

Comment: @Bwolfing still not understand

Comment: At what line is the error occurring? It looks like the line is in comment now. For example I see `Application.Current.Properties["user"]` that is a candidate for this error. `"user"` is the key and if it isn't in the `Application.Current.Properties` it will throw an error like this. You should check if the key exists, if not add it and then you can assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Xamarin.Forms related issue but a basic C# exception that is not specially related to Xamarin or Xamarin.Forms.

1. Please check MSDN for [`KeyNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a35cy81).

> The exception that is thrown when the key specified for accessing an
> element in a collection does not match any key in the collection.

2. Debug your code to see at what line the exception gets thrown exactly.

   As your screenshot shows you seem to be using Visual Studio. MSDN has a nice article on how to get your debugging going here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx